# Pass Base64 jpeg image to og:image

Tags: php, html, facebook, base64, share-open-graph

I have image that is being generated in runtime on my website and I display it in html using

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<!-- base64 data -->" />
```

Now, I want for Facebook to fetch this image, but if I do the same for og:image meta tag, facebook debugger gives me an error. Any solution?

```
<meta property='og:image' content='data:image/jpeg;base64,<!-- base64 data -->'/>
```

Of course, I would like to avoid permanent saving of files since they are always different and it would get too crowded very quickly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Paste it to a PHP file that echos it out:

```php
    <meta property='og:image' content='decoder.php?data=<!-- base64 data -->'/>
```

`decoder.php`:

```php
    <?php
        echo base64_decode($_GET['data']);
    ?>
```

**EDIT**
Make sure you check source for security reasons.

Comment: this seems like good solution. Just one question. Won't the url for decoder.php be too long?

Comment: shouldn't be problem in new browsers (and for fb!)

Comment: @exim I have the following error: 414 (Request-URI Too Large)

Comment: @neoDev Yep, I'm getting 414 too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891574/how-do-i-resolve-a-http-414-request-uri-too-long-error (hint: use smaller images or change server configuration)

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger just change the endpoint to a nodeJS endpoint. The language isn't important, it is just doing a get request. This is highly inefficient, but an interesting solution.

Answer (score 4):

Open Graph *needs* an URL.

You could try saving your base64 as a temp image.

Comment: How, could I do this?
I have tried this

    `$temp = tmpfile();
    fwrite($temp, "data:image/jpeg;base64,".$data);`
But then i have resource.

Comment: temp files will not be always available. They may be deleted in any time.

Answer (score 0):

If the images is saved in a db as a blob you can get the image using the following:

image_generator.php:

```
$imageID = $_GET['id'];

$image = // Fetch the image from database using an id;

// Set the appropriate content type for the image (e.g., JPEG)
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    
// Output the image data directly
echo $image;
```

og tag creation:

```
$imageID = // id referred to the image
$imageUrl = "https://yoururl/image_generator.php?id=$imageID";
echo "<meta property='og:image' content='$imageUrl' />
```