# How to pass base64 jpeg image to ogimage?

Tags: facebook, share-open-graph

I have image that is being generated in runtime on my website and I display it in html using

```
img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<!-- base64 data -->"
```

Now, I want for Facebook to fetch this image, but if I do the same for og:image meta tag, facebook debugger gives me an error. Any solution?

```
meta property='og:image' content='data:image/jpeg;base64,<!-- base64 data -->'
```

Of course, I would like to avoid permanent saving of files since they are always different and it would get too crowded very quickly.

Reference URL: http://www.seemasandesh.com/epaper.aspx?blogid=9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Base64 jpeg image to og:image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460421/pass-base64-jpeg-image-to-ogimage)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. It have to be a public url so Facebook can download it when they need it. They will just cache it so there need to be a url to the original image