# Generate a custom preview image based on parameters

Tags: html, meta, preview

When I share a link to a location on Google Maps, the link comes with a preview image of that location, like this:

[image: screenshot of a preview image appearing when sharing a google maps link]

From what I know, you can put a preview image as a  tag in the  section of a webpage, like this:

`<meta property="og:image" content="example.png"/>`

But this tag is static and there isn't really a way to make it dynamic. So how does Google Maps do it?

Answer (score 0):

Google might be doing something special, because they're Google, but it's definitely possible to make it dynamic server-side. If a sevrer renders a page using a template and knows something about the route it's rendering, it can swap out the image for another one or even generate it on the fly, for example as a base64 image as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460421/pass-base64-jpeg-image-to-ogimage).

An example of this using Jinja templates (for Python) would be `<meta property="og:image" content="{{ map_location.thumbnail }}"/>`. A more complex example using JavaScript template strings might be:

```
render(
  `
  <html>
  <!-- other content -->
  <meta property="og:image" content="/images/${request.parameters.id}.png"/>
  <!-- other content -->
  </html>
  `
)
```