# Fetch Blog data type into meta tag content as image

Tags: php, meta-tags

I store article data in in article table and "image" column have blob data type

I have my php code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles`
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $image = $row['image'];
            $head = $row['head'];
            $content = $row['content'];
            $createdBy = $row['createdBy'];
            $date = $row['date'];
        }
    }
```

I have meta tag:

```
<meta property='og:image' content="<?php echo $iamge ?>"/>
```

I am expecting my source code of meta tag as:

```
<meta property='og:image' content="image_source"/>
```

Note: in "img" tag's src attribute I got image and successfully displayed. But in "meta" tag's content attribute I didn't get image source.

but I get:

```
<meta property='og:image' content="dkjhasdjjkhjkasdjkjkka...."/>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Typo, `$iamge`? Is `image` a image location, image itself, or encoded version of an image?

Comment: Look at this answer. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460421/pass-base64-jpeg-image-to-ogimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460421/pass-base64-jpeg-image-to-ogimage)

Comment: Just FYI: Facebook does not process Data URIs for og:image. If you want this to work for sharing on Facebook, you must supply a publicly reachable HTTP(S) URL to begin with.