# Flask Error: 414 Request-URI Too Large

Tags: python, apache, flask

I'm using Flask with Apache. When I send a GET request with a long url (19000+ characters), the response is

```
Status 414: Request-URI Too Large.
```

I suspect that the request triggers a `werkzeug RequestURITooLarge Exception` or a flask `HTTPException`. When I send a request with similar url length to Apache directly there is no error.

Is there a way to increase the maximum url length that Flask handles?

Comment: ¿Can you use post data to get the page?

Comment: Yes, I could use a POST request. However, I want to know if a GET request is possible. For my application, the request does not create any side effects on the server, so I'd prefer to use a GET.

Comment: Do you know that Apache isn't triggering the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use POST instead of GET, but if you don't need to use it i think this question have related answer for your problem.

[How do I resolve a HTTP 414 "Request URI too long" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891574/how-do-i-resolve-a-http-414-request-uri-too-long-error)

Comment: Ok, the error was with Apache. I exceeded the default HTTP request-line limit of 8190 bytes. Following the advice in the question referenced above, I changed the Apache LimitRequestLine configuration directive, and that solves the issue. I can now support long urls.

Comment: great, but also try to use POST because you may forget to make this configuration in the deployment process :)