# How to send a string to php with POST

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm sending a string via xmlhttp in javascript using the following code:

```
    function SendPHP(str, callback) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {


                         callback(xmlhttp.responseText); //invoke the callback
        }
    }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "testpost.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(str), true);

    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

and some test php:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
echo $q;
```

That worked fine until I started sending a larger string in which case I get the "HTTP/1.1 414 Request-URI Too Long" error.

After a bit of research I found out I need to use "POST" instead. So I changed it to:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "sendmail.php?q=" + str, true);
```

And:

```
$q = $_POST['q'];
echo $q;
```

But this does not echo anything when using POST. How can I fix it so it works like when I was using GET but so it can handle a large string of data?

*edit* I'm now trying it with:

```
function testNewPHP(str){


    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

str = "q=" + encodeURIComponent(str);

  alert (str);

xmlhttp.open("POST","testpost.php", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
     if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                            alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
     }
    }
  };
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(str);

}
```

Comment: You do not POST variables using url parameters, they are sent through the [send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send())

Comment: I'm basically using it to send a CSV file turned into a string to my php script which does some processing on it. So it's just a long string that needs to be processed by the php script.

Comment: see this link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891574/how-do-i-resolve-a-http-414-request-uri-too-long-error

Comment: @Saman I read that before to figure out I need to use POST instead of GET, but it doesn't say the difference on how to use it vs GET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not provide your href with URL parameters, instead of this you should `send()` them. For addition, you should always encode your parameters with `encodeURIComponent()` (At least when your request is using the `Content-type` `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`).

your javascript function :

```
function testNewPHP(){
var str = "This is test";

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

str = "q=" + encodeURIComponent(str);

alert (str);

xmlhttp.open("POST","testpost.php", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
            alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(str);

}
```

Comment: @tadman: I was just editing that thing.Fast!!

Comment: Couldn't let that mistake get in the way of your great answer. Heh.

Comment: The str string in my code is the contents of a CSV file. In this answer is it overwritten with something? I'm not sure I understand the json part.

Comment: Sorry, it is a block from my code, I've updated it

Comment: No response so far, do I have to change the php part?

Comment: The alert(str) gives me something like: q=Paia%5E!keyur.paa%40yahoo.co.uk%5E!%3C ... which is the csv data. 

I changed the php to var_dump($post), but I can't see the result because it hasn't returned?

Comment: Yep, that's what I put. I edited my question to show the function that I'm using for the xmlhttp.. not sure if something is wrong there.

Comment: Are you checking var_dump() output in page resources window ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how I do that? I only thought I could see the result when it gets returned to the javascript

Comment: open safari or google chrome,then open Development->Show page resources in Safari or Tools->Development Tools->Network in Chrome. There you can see pages that you are requesting via ajax and it's output.

Comment: Ok, I got that open. I'm on the javascript page and running the function to call the xmlhttp, but I don't see any result of the vardump, on the console it says :" Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined "... not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: So can you see output by clicking on "testpost.php" in Resources(it is common both for Chrome and Safari) panel?

Comment: No, it has the html files and the js files there but no php

Comment: It means that you are not using (or using it incorrectly) your js function SendPHP

Comment: Hmm, it was working fine when I was using GET. I'll change it back to the old GET code and see what's wrong.

Comment: Then at last try your old php script with your new js function.It should work out).It kinda getting me crazy , so I really want to help at least to figure out what the problem was.

Comment: Ok, I used the old javascript code and I can see the vardump in chrome resources with that. So I'll try and figure out what went wrong with the new js code and why it doesnt show the vardump

Comment: try to set `content-type` to `"text/csv; charset=utf-8"`.Try to use with and without encodeURIComponent() and post your results.

Comment: I changed it (shown at the bottom of my edited question), still no joy.

Comment: I edited my question to show the function I was using that was working before when I used GET. Could it be because there is no " xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();" in the new one?

Comment: Aha! I added that and now it returns "NULL"

Comment: Change `content-type` to the previous value. Sorry, I've used this function to auto detect xmlhttp object depending on browser type.

Comment: Ok, still returning Null ... the str string is fine before being sent "q=This%20is%20a%20test"

Comment: So I just put JSON.stringify(str), and how do I assign to key 'q'?

Comment: I really can't get what the problem is, cause when i run it on my machine with string `"This is test"` I get correct var_dump in my php script

Comment: Hmm, strange. I might have to give up on this and just use a function to parse the csv in chunks using GET. Thanks a lot for your help though, sorry you wasted so much of your time!

Comment: Just tried that and it still returns null

Comment: I see ok, hmmm. I wonder why the data is invalid on my end but not yours? I also tried the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest solution, just copying and pasting the function but that returns null as well.

Comment: I am writing another answer and after that you just copy it and post the output,OK?

Answer (score 1):

javascript :

```
 function testNewPHP(){
var str = "This is test";

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

str = "q=" + encodeURIComponent(str);

alert (str);

xmlhttp.open("POST","testpost.php", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
            alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(str);

}
```

testpost.php in your home directory :

```
<?php
 var_dump($_POST);
```

OUTPUT :

```
array(1) {
["q"]=>
string(12) "This is test"
}
```

Comment: What was the problem in the end?

Comment: I have not fixed out what the problem was, Could you?)

Comment: Cool, done! Haha, no idea what the problem was in the end.

Comment: Glad to help you,anyway)))