# Reading file over http in java: HTTP response code 414

Tags: java, http, url, response

I'm currently writing a java program that reads tab-delimited text files via http.
This is what I do:

```
String urlString = http://www.uniprot.org/mapping/?from=BIOGRID_ID&to=ACC&format=tab&query=1194477,116761,.....
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(urlString).openStream()));
```

Usually this works for me, but now I get

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 414 for URL: http://...
```

which means the URL is too long.
Is there a solution other than sending multiple smaller requests?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Error 414 means that web server thinks that the HTTP data stream sent by the client contains a URL that is simply too large i.e. too many bytes.

If you're using Apache you can change the `LimitRequestLine` directive value to change the data stream URL length.
For more details check this : [How do I resolve a HTTP 414 "Request URI too long" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2891574/1623602)