# Wordpress - link stops working after adding GET parameters to it

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, url, url-parameters

This link works just fine: [first link](https://www.creativebrands.co.za/clothing/golf-shirts-clothing/)

While this one reponds with empty page: [second link](https://www.creativebrands.co.za/clothing/golf-shirts-clothing/?ga_campaign=CB%20-%20Search%20-%20Clothing%20-%20Golf%20Shirts&ga_source=google&ga_medium=cpc&ga_content=152245732725&ga_term=%2Bpromotional%20%2Bgolf%20%2Bshirts&gclid=CjwKEAjw7svABRCi_KPzoPr53QoSJAABSvxfG4-yYgeojF1Uhc_LKd3AcSlSPW_dLuvHqFtdsmTLVxoCDLbw_wcB)

[image]

What can be the problem?
Is the URL too long?
Or is something wrong with the GET parameters I provided?

The site is built with Wordpress, and I'm using the latest version of Chrome browser.

Comment: If your URL was too long, you would be getting an error message. WordPress already uses a GET parameter to pass the current content and hides it with URL rewrite. Try adding & instead of ?

Comment: I just tried it repeatedly, and it's definitely related to the length of the URL. You can shorten it a bit and remove one character and it works fine, add one character and it breaks. This is a new one I haven't seen before.. URL maximums are supposed to be around like 8000 characters!

Comment: @Greg not really ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/1427878

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a server configuration issues. The web page returns a 414 code, which means the request-URI is too long. More details are available here: https://httpstatuses.com/414.

You are using Apache, maybe the following link could help you. Quickly, you need to increase `LimitRequestLine` configuration in your httpd.conf. If the configuration doesn't exist, you can add it at the bottom of your httpd.conf. The default value of `LimitRequestLine` is 8190.

Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891598/1164005