# Url that have been passed to long

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Im writing this code for save an url in a file txt, that i will use too pass after the same for invoke the button share.
my problem come when i use this code

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "/condividi.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    res: osrm_result
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert("ciaociao");
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2F52.16.81.189%2Findex_gen.html&amp;src=sdkpreparse");
  }
});
```

this trigger the error: Url too long 
how i can correct this to make it work

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891574/how-do-i-resolve-a-http-414-request-uri-too-long-error

Comment: It's not clear if the URL causing the error is the one specified for ajax or the one in window.open. Please clarify.

Comment: URL parameters are simply not designed to contain large amounts of information. You should be using POST.

Comment: you did not specify a type in your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

the default method which jQuery uses is GET which has limited data length,
try sending the data by POST (you should of course update the condividi.php accordingly to serve the POST request):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/condividi.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    res: osrm_result
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert("ciaociao");
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2F52.16.81.189%2Findex_gen.html&amp;src=sdkpreparse");
  }
});
```

Comment: you can up-vote this answer if it helped so in the future, people are directed to the accepted answer