# Laravel 7: How to pass variable inside string?

Tags: laravel, string

I'm using a Laravel Package for sending SMS. Package Link: https://github.com/arif98741/laravelbdsms

sms_settings Table:

| id | ac_open | ac_open_sms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Hello {$name}, Your Account has been created |

My controller:

```
 $sms_settings = SmsSetting::where('id', 1)->first();
 $name = $request->name;
 $msg =  $sms_settings->ac_open_sms;
 $send= SMS::shoot($request->mobile, $msg);
```

Here I want to save the message body in database. While saving I want to pass a varibale `$name`. So that I can show the name anywhere in message body.
While sending the message it shows client error.
If I set the message body like this:  `$msg =  "{$name}, \r\n Your account has been created";` it works.

How can I make it work?

Comment: You will need to replace the variable with the value, where is your replacement operation?

Comment: I'm saving the message body from a textarea input field. I'm not sure about replacement operation. Can you please show a demo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `str_replace` to replace the `{name}` with what you get from request.
I don't really understand the logic but here you go:

```
str_replace("{$name}",$name,$msg);
```

Also quick tip, instead of

```
 $sms_settings = SmsSetting::where('id', 1)->first();
```

You can try:

```
 $sms_settings = SmsSetting::findOrFail(1);
```

Comment: you don't need the quotes around $name and $msg

Comment: @GertB. true that, edited. was  quick response, ty

Comment: From package documentation I found this: 
SMS::shoot('017XXYYZZAA', 'helloooooooo boss!');
First parameter will be number and second will be message. 
In message I want to pass a custom message from database where customer name will be included.

Comment: I am saving data to `ac_open_sms` this column from a textarea field.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I tried before with str_replace but in wrong way. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, It works for english only. What to do for other language?

Comment: @ShanMdShazarulHaque171-15- What do you mean for another language? Can you put  an example?

Comment: When I put `Hello` in message body there is no error. But if I write any other language it shows error. Like 'হ্যালো' , I write in Bengali it shows error.

Comment: Can you show the error please? I can't help you with just words @ShanMdShazarulHaque171-15-

Comment: Client error: `GET https://smsplus.sslwireless.com/api/v3/send-sms?api_token=dj96arla` resulted in a `414 Request-URI Too Long` response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "

Comment: @ShanMdShazarulHaque171-15- that error doesn't mean the code i provided is wrong. It's saying something else. Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891574/how-do-i-resolve-a-http-414-request-uri-too-long-error

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. And thanks again

Comment: GET https://smsplus.sslwireless.com/api/v3/send-sms?api_token=dj96arla resulted in a 414 Request-URI Too Long is solved recently. update your package and you will not face this issue any more. Tool long error was occured due to bengali unicode as I was using GET request in package. But this is changed to POST request now. 
I want to mention that I am owner of laravelbdsms package

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the placeholder with:

```
$msg =  str_replace('{$name}', $name, $sms_settings->ac_open_sms);
```

or use translations with variables:

replace `{$name}` with `:name` and:

```
$msg = __($sms_settings->ac_open_sms, ['name' => $name]);
```

With the last option you can also translate the message in the future

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand you want to pass user name instead of {$name}

so you can pass name before save message in database  like this
`$msg =  "$name, \r\n Your account has been created";` or
`$msg =  $name . ", \r\n Your account has been created";`

if you want to pass user name after select row from database or before shoot sms you can do this

```
$msg=str_replace("Jo","{$name}",$sms_settings->ac_open_sms);
```

Comment: I want to send sms while creating a customer account. And the sms body will be custom which will come from database. and In sms  body I want to pass the Customer name with name variable

Comment: Your str_replace properties are in the wrong order : `str_replace($search, $replace, $subject)`