# How to cache an HTTP POST response?

Tags: http, browser, caching, post, cross-browser

I would like to create a cacheable HTTP response for a POST request.

My actual implementation responds the following for the POST request:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Expires: Sat, 03 Oct 2020 15:33:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private,max-age=315360000,no-transform
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 9
ETag: 2120507660800737950
Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Oct 2010 15:33:00 GMT

.........
```

But it looks like that the browsers (Safari, Firefox tested) are not caching the response.

In the [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) the corresponding part says:

> Responses to this method are not cacheable unless the response includes appropriate Cache-Control or Expires header fields. However, the 303 (See Other) response can be used to direct the user agent to retrieve a cacheable resource.

So I think it should be cached. I know I could set a session variable and set a cookie and do a 303 redirect, but I want to cache the response of the POST request.

Is there any way to do this?

P.S.: I've started with a simple `200 OK`, so it does not work.

Comment: The response to a post is usually unique depending on the posted parameters, so it generally makes no sense to cache it. What is your response? I have a feeling you're doing something else not entirely right.

Comment: It would be a store like thing. If somebody posts something to an URL it will store the content on the specified location for this client. So the client could cache it and does not need to recheck the location because it'll be the same as it posted for this current client.

Comment: I solved the actual problem with an AJAX GET request with a custom header (for the value). But I'm still interested in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to cache POST methods in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd also note that caching is always optional (it's a MAY in the HTTP/1.1 RFC). Since under most circumstances, a successful POST *invalidates* a cache entry, it's probably simply the case that the browser caches you're looking at just don't implement caching POST responses (since this would be pretty uncommon--usually this is accomplished by formatting things as a GET, which it sounds like you've done).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: POST caching rarely makes sense. A cache may serve GET requests to a URL which is the same as that of a previous POST, whose response came with a Content-Location header containing the POST's request URI.

From [rfc-7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) (http-bis, superseding rfc-2616):

> Responses to POST requests are only cacheable when they include
> explicit freshness information (see Section 4.2.1 of [RFC7234]).
> However, POST caching is not widely implemented.  For cases where an
> origin server wishes the client to be able to cache the result of a
> POST in a way that can be reused by a later GET, the origin server
> MAY send a 200 (OK) response containing the result and a
> Content-Location header field that has the same value as the POST's
> effective request URI (Section 3.1.4.2).

See also [Mark Nottinghams Blog](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/09/24/caching_POST):

> POSTs don't deal in representations of identified state, 99 times out
> of 100. However, there is one case where it does; when the server goes
> out of its way to say that this POST response is a representation of
> its URI, by setting a Content-Location header that's the same as the
> request URI. When that happens, the POST response is just like a GET
> response to the same URI; it can be cached and reused -- but only for
> future GET requests.

The rfc also describes a [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) sequence which has a similar effect, allowing the response cycle to a POST to fill the cache for a subsequent GET - which is probably more widely implemented.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to change the `Cache-Control` to `public` instead of `private` and see if it's working?

Comment: i'll try but the content should not be cached publicly