# ASIHTTPRequest Cache response data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, asihttprequest

I'm trying a lot with `ASIHTTPRequest` to `cache` the response data, I have read the documentation and tried many solutions, but no luck :(

This is my code:

```
_request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"kBaseUrl", nil)]];
_request.delegate = self;
[_request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] setShouldRespectCacheControlHeaders:NO];
[_request setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy|ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];//ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy|ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy
[_request setSecondsToCache:60*60*24*2]; // Cache for 2 days
[_request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
[_request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[_request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(doneLoadingBody:)];
[_request setDidFailSelector:@selector(failedLoadingBody:)];
[_request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[_request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[_request setPostValue:@"someValue" forKey:@"name"];
[_request setPostValue:@"someValue" forKey:@"key"];
[_request setPostValue:@"someValue" forKey:@"key"];
[_request startAsynchronous];

if ([_request didUseCachedResponse] == NO) {

    NSLog(@"Did not Cache Body");

}
```

Comment: Stop using ASIHTTPRequest and start using AFNetworking. ASI is unsupported for quite few years now (I don't think they even have ARC support).

Comment: @Eimantas i'm planning to move to AFNetworking but not at the current time.. i'm working on an existing project with the ASIHTTPRequest, so I need some time before moving to AFNetworking.

Answer (score 0):

You're using ASIFormDataRequest and it's basically a POST operation.

Since POST is not an idempotent operation, i doubt it is cacheable.

Maybe you should start testing your cache mechanism with a GET request.

Some reference: [Is it possible to cache POST methods in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http)