# how to cache post requests with varnish?

Tags: caching, post, request, docker, varnish

I use varnish with docker - see [million12/varnish](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/million12/varnish/)

GET requests work great !

but i have no idea what i have to set in the settings to cache POST requests.

on google i have found many posts (from 2010 or 2011) where it says that POST requests can not be cached with varnish - is this statement still correct?

Or is there another way to cache POST requests?

here my **varnish.vcl** settings:

```
vcl 4.0;
backend default {
    ...
}

# Respond to incoming requests.
sub vcl_recv {
  unset req.http.Cookie;
}

# Set a header to track a cache HIT/MISS.
sub vcl_deliver {
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT";
  }
  else {
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "MISS";
  }
}

# Not cache 400 - 500 status requests
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.status >= 400 && beresp.status <= 600) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
  }
}
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Why do you want to cache Post requests? I think is conceptually wrong. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http)

Comment: I calculate big things with an internal API in our company.
There are almost the same POST requests.
And thats why I am looking for a solution to cache POST requests for a better performance

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you check that in your backend?

Comment: Why are those POST requests? Are they modifying any state on the server?

Comment: @Redithion Yes it would be better .. but i have no chance to change that.. my boss don't want to change the Internal API .. yeah stupid i know. Thats why i need an example to cache POST and GET requests with a Docker Container. It does not have to be made with Varnish. If you have an other example - i would also be happy !

Comment: You may want to check [this](https://medium.com/programming-articles/caching-post-responses-with-nginx-1c0c064bb6b0)

Answer (score 6):

Edit Dec. 2020:

There is an updated tutorial for this here:
https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/caching-post-requests/

---

There is a Varnish module and tutorial for caching POST requests.  This adds the ability to add the post body to the hash key and to pass along the POST request.

> The VMOD is available for Varnish 4 releases and includes the following
> functions:
>
> ```
> buffer_req_body(BYTES size): buffers the request body if it is smaller
>     than size. This function is a “better” (bug-free**) copy of
>     std.CacheReqBody(), so please use this one instead of the one provided
>     by the libvmod-std. Please note that retrieving req.body makes it
>     possible to retry pass operations(POST, PUT).
>
> len_req_body(): returns the request body length.
>
> rematch_req_body(STRING re): regular expression match on request body.
>
> hash_req_body(): adds body bytes to the input hash key.
> ```

https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/caching-post-requests-with-varnish
https://github.com/aondio/libvmod-bodyaccess

Note that in the 4.1 branch of this VMOD, the built in `std.cache_req_body()` is used instead of `buffer_req_body()`, but a standing bug in Varnish 4.1 breaks the 4.1 branch.  https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/1927

Answer (score 5):

Currently Varnish **can't cache POST requests**.

AFAIK people's tries to cache POST request have failed. It seems that Varnish ends up converting those into GET requests.

Sources:

- [A Blog](https://medium.com/programming-articles/caching-post-responses-with-nginx-1c0c064bb6b0) (with additional information about how to do it with Nginx)
- [Varnish Forum](https://www.varnish-cache.org/forum/topic/235)

Comment: I think this is no longer actual.

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny can you provide further information about that?

Comment: I meant an answer by @Laizer.

Comment: You can tell varnish to use `POST` for the backend request: ```sub vcl_backend_fetch {
  if (bereq.http.X-Body-Len) {
      set bereq.method = "POST";
  }
}```

Answer (score 0):

- put another ngnx/apache/whatever on an unused port
- push the POST request to that server
- over there you forward them to the varnish as a get request and fetch the result
- display the result via your relay-server

will probably slow down the whole thing a bit - but we are talking dirty workarounds here right? Hope this is not a way too crazy solution..