# cachecow with http post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, cachecow

I am thinking of adding cachecow to our production web api. All the examples I see are for GET requests. The endpoint I would like to cache is a POST request that takes a view model of many search filters. I can not seem to find the answer to my question - Will cachecow work for POST requests and cache results based on the search filters? If 30 different search filters come in will there be 30 cached results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caching of POSTs is generally not supported / a grey area at HTTP level.

See this other SO question:

[Is it possible to cache POST methods in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http)

I would change the method to a GET request if you need to support caching.