# IOS - URLCache not caching post request?

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to implement a caching for my `POST` request, but when i try to retrieve the cache it always return `nil`. The cache work fine if the request is `GET`

any idea how to make `URLCache` cache my post request?

thanks!

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Comment: Nice to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk thanks for the link, its really helpful