# Caching responses with JSON-RPC

Tags: rest, api, caching, cache-control, json-rpc

In REST we can cache responses by URL, but in JSON-RPC all data a passed in body, so how can we cache responses in JSON-RPC? Is it possible to cache responses on client?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to cache POST methods in HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JSON-RPC from a browser then you can make a cache with local storage and it will better because actually cashing is always sophisticated thing.