# Impact in terms of response time if we only use POST instead of other REST verbs?

Tags: rest, http-verbs

I read it in this [post](https://medium.com/@suhas_chatekar/why-you-should-use-the-recommended-http-methods-in-your-rest-apis-981359828bf7) that

> An operation behind a GET endpoint does not change the target state of
>   the server therefore the response of a GET endpoint can be cached
>   resulting in further requests to the same endpoint being returned
>   faster from the cache
>
> An endpoint behind PUT, POST, PATCH and DELETE changes the target state of the server therefore a successful response out of any of these endpoints can be used to bust the previously cached responses.

So using `GET` wherever we can, can impact performance(faster responses).

But only using `POST` instead of other verbs `PUT, POST, PATCH and DELETE`, can this impact performance(faster responses) in any way or it is just for developers to understand what the API's does?

Thanks.

Comment: Taking a look at https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html could shed some light on this issue. I especially recommend the section about "Safe and Idempotent Methods".

Comment: @LutzHorn RFC 2616 got obsolete by RFC 7230-7235 (i.e. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4)

Comment: HTTP is a protocol for managing resources on remote machines Any business rules you infer from interacting with HTTP servers are just side effects of the resource management actually. Each of the verbs defines certain semantics that enable interoperability as long as each peer sticks to the same semantics. The safe property is useful for i.e. crawler which assume that invoking a URI is safe for them (i.e. does not trigger a order for something or deletes user records or what not).

Comment: @RomanVottner So is there any performance impact? As we can see in terms of using GET.

Comment: It depends on what you understand as performance impact. `GET` resposes are cachable by default which allows intermediary (or the serivce itself) to simply return a previously calculated state, so the servcie actually might never take notice of the request to start with - best performance improvment there is. POST responses are only cacheable if they contain [explicit refreshness information](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-4.2.1). If the actual performed action on the server are more performant than other methods depend on the implementation of the business logic actually.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http

Comment: My advice (decades of experience).  Don't get tricky regardless of the performance increase (most likely minor).  You WILL regret it.  I have seen someone use ALL gets (even for updates) in an attempt to "speed it up".  Did not work out well.

Comment: @JohnWhite Thanks for your advice but as it is nearly 2.5 times faster than normal HTTP protocol, I think it is a much-needed thing.