# Ajax doesnt cache requests

Tags: javascript, file, caching

How can I get the contents of a file using JS, **while letting the file be cached by the browser**?

One possible way is to make that file a `.js` and let it be `var SuperVar = 'BASE64-ENCODED-CONTENT'` (base64 to escape special chars), but access and maintenance of the real contents would become indeed hard. **I am trying to have normal files after all.**

As the files are in size of 1-100 KB and of an unlimited quantity, so is `localStorage` not an option (will run out of space).

Have tried with `<iframe>`. Browsers parse `.html` files somewhat fine. Files need to begin with `<html>` else they get wrapped in a `<pre>` tag. By other filetypes IE creates an `<object>` and offers the file for download.

The point is for JS to work with the same file contents on multiple page loads without downloading them every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use AJAX, which will use the cache, if your server is configured correctly, and if you make GET requests.

```js
btn.onclick = function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.response.substr(0, 20));
  };
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js');
  xhr.send();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Open your dev-tools Network panel to see how it has been transferred.</p>
<button id="btn">request jQuery</button>
```

Comment: You said "you probably have to do a GET request" which means it may also be POST? Please clarify this and "if your server is configured correctly" and any other details necessary for a cached ajax

Comment: @Krupp I don't really have time to go into details right now sorry. But it is the same as with any other request, you need a Cache-Control header. As for POST, it is theoretically possible, but for which implementations do respect this... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http

Answer (score 0):

You have to send cache-control header from your server to let browser cache your ajax request.

**index.html**

```
<button id="btn">GET</button>
<script>
    btn.onclick = function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.open('GET', 'cached.php');
        xhr.send();
    };
</script>
```

**cached.php**

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=60');
echo file_get_contents("file.any");
```

**file.any**

```
Contents
of
File...
```

> You will see the status code 200, but if you check the **Size** column
>   in chrome developer-tools you can see if it was loaded from cache.

[image: chrome developer tools network panel]