# Avoid caching 205 responses

Tags: html, forms, http, caching, etag

A dynamic-post-form that should be cached using eTag. Navigation:

1. A user browse to the form `form.html` and recieve the status 200 having the new eTag `"DNEI297"` within the response from the server. Now the browser caches this document in the cache.
2. The user enters some values and finally post the form-data to `form.html` (browser to server) and recieve from the server the [HTTP status code 205](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.6) (accepted/reset form data) and the unchanged eTag `"DNEI297"`.
3. Since the 205 response is empty in this case, the browser reload the page `form.html` using the eTag `"DNEI297"`. The server compares the eTag with his eTag and decide that neither the form nor the eTag changed and the browser already have cached the correct version of the `form.html` and send a 304 (unchanged).

Now the Problem: Since the Server sent a 304 the Browser took the last request and decide to use the cached version. But the cached version is the answer of the post-request having status-code 205 and the eTag `"DNEI297"`.

Finally after the submit of the form the document http-status is 205. How to avoid the wrong code? It makes trouble and produce alerts from antivirus-plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The server in this case erred by sending the same `ETag`—or any `ETag`—in its `205` response to the form submission.

[RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2) describes when it's appropriate to use an `ETag`:

> A "strong validator" is representation metadata that changes value
> whenever a change occurs to the representation data that would be
> observable in the payload body of a `200 (OK)` response to `GET`.

So you should not send an `ETag` along with the empty `205` response, since that's not what you'd get by doing a successful `GET` to that URL.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the eTag from the 205 response but the behavior remains unchnaged, even in a new in-private tab.

Comment: @Grim: Using a private browser window doesn't prevent access to the cache; you need to explicitly clear the cache for your site. The bigger issue is that this behavior ("the cached version is the answer of the post-request") is just extremely unlikely, as browsers generally do not cache responses to `POST` requests at all unless you take pains to make that happen (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http) for example). So you're probably going to have to edit the question to include full requests and response headers for each step.