# AWS Cloudfront Origin Groups "cannot include POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE for a cached behavior"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have two paths in a CloudFront distribution which have the following Behaviors:

| Path Pattern | Origin | Viewer Protocol Policy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /api/* | APIOriginGroup | Redirect HTTP to HTTPS |
| /* | S3OriginGroup | Redirect HTTP to HTTPS |

And these Origins:

| Origin Name | Origin Domain | Origin Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S3Origin1 | us-east-1.s3.[blah] | S3OriginGroup |
| S3Origin2 | us-east-2.s3.[blah] | S3OriginGroup |
| APIOrigin1 | a domain | APIOriginGroup |
| APIOrigin2 | a domain | APIOriginGroup |

This setup works fine for GET requests, but if I add POST requests into the [Cache Behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior.html)'s Cache Methods I get an error:

"cannot include POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE for a cached behavior"

This doesn't make sense to me. If CloudFront really is used by [AWS customers to serve billions of requests per day](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/enhanced-origin-failover-using-amazon-cloudfront-and-aws-lambdaedge/) and AWS recommends using CloudFront Origin Failover, which ?requires origin groups?, then it follows that there must be some way to configure CloudFront to allow origin behaviors which allow POST requests. Is this not true? Are all of these API requests being made by this customer GET requests?

To be clear, my fundamental problem is that I want to use CloudFront Origin Failover to switch between my primary region and secondary region when an AWS region fails. To make that possible, I need to switch over not only my front end, S3-based traffic (GET requests), but also switch over my back-end traffic (POST requests).

Note: CloudFront supports routing behaviors with POST requests if you do not use an Origin Group. It seems that only when I added this Origin Group (to support the second region) that this error appeared.

Comment: You're mistaking cache for failover logic - you normally 99.99% of the time cache reads, not 'writes' as PUT/PATCH/DELETEs would be.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I am not trying to cache POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE requests. I am trying to use CloudFront Origin Failover to 'fail over' from us-east-1 to us-east-2 if us-east-1 becomes unavailable at my API endpoint. The alternative strategies of which I am aware are: (1) use health checks and failover via Route53 configuration; (2) Have the client code initiate a request to the secondary region if the request to the primary region fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short Answer:** You can't do origin failover in CloudFront for request methods other than `GET`, `HEAD`, or `OPTIONS`. Period.

**TL; DR**

`CloudFront` caches `GET` and `HEAD` requests always. It can be configured to cache `OPTIONS` requests too. However it doesn't cache `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`,... requests which is consistent with the most of the public CDNs out there. However, some of them might provide you with writing some sort of custom hooks by virtue of which you can cache `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`,... requests. You might be wondering why is that? Why can't I cache `POST` requests? The answer to that question is `RFC 2616`. Since `POST` requests are not idempotent, the specification advises against caching them and sending them to the end server intended, indeed, always. There's a very nice [SO thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http#:%7E:text=%22Responses%20to%20POST%20method%20are,want%20to%20cache%20the%20response.) which you can read to have a better understanding.

> `CloudFront` fails over to the secondary origin only when the `HTTP` method of the viewer request is `GET`, `HEAD`, or `OPTIONS`. CloudFront does not fail over when the viewer sends a different HTTP method (for example `POST`, `PUT`, and so on).

**Ok. `POST` requests are not cached by CloudFront. But, why does CloudFront not provide failover for `POST` requests?**

Let's see how does CloudFront handle requests in case of a primary origin failure. See below:

[image]

> `CloudFront` routes all incoming requests to the primary origin, even when a previous request failed over to the secondary origin. `CloudFront` only sends requests to the secondary origin after a request to the primary origin fails.

Now, since `POST` requests are not cached `CloudFront` has to go to the primary origin each time, come back with an invalid response or worst a time-out, then hit the secondary origin in the origin group. We're talking about region failures here. The failover requests from primary to secondary would be ridiculously high and we might expect a cascading failure due to high load. This would lead to CloudFront PoP failures and this defeats the whole purpose of high availability, doesn't it? Again, this explanation is only my assumption. Of course, I'm sure folks at CloudFront would come up with a solution for handling `POST` requests region failover soon.

**So far so good. But how are other AWS customers able to guarantee high availability to their users in case of AWS region failures.**

Well other AWS customers only use CloudFront region failover to make their static websites, SPAs, static contents like videos (live and on demand), images, etc failure proof which by the way only requires `GET`, `HEAD` and occasionally `OPTION` `HTTP` requests. Imagine a SaaS company which drives its sales and discoverability via a static website. If you could reduce your downtime by the method above which would ensure your sales/growth doesn't take a hit, why wouldn't you?

**Got the point. But I do really need to have region failover for my backend APIs. How can I do it?**

One way would be to write a custom `Lambda@Edge` function. `CloudFront` hits the intended primary origin, the code inside checks for time-out/response codes/etc and if failover has to be triggered, hits the other origin's endpoint and returns the response. This is again in contradictory to the current schemes of `CloudFront`.

Another solution would be, which in my opinion is much cleaner, is to make use of latency-based routing support of Route53. You can read about how to do that [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/latency-based-routing-leveraging-amazon-cloudfront-for-a-multi-region-active-active-architecture/). While this method would surely work for your backend APIs if you had different subdomain names for your S3 files and APIs (and those subdomains pointing to different `CloudFront` distributions) since it leverages `CloudFront` canonical names, I'm a bit skeptical if this would work in your setup. You can try and test it out, anyways.

**Edit**: As suggested by OP, there is a third approach to achieve this which is to handle this on the client side. Whenever client receives an unexpected response code or a timeout it makes an API call to another endpoint which is hosted on another region. This solution is a bit cheaper and simpler and easier to implement with current scheme of things available.